# Linq join on objects with navigation property - how to improve performance

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I have an Entity Framework 5 model with 4 tables and I need to create a LINQ query against them. I am not able to modify the DB structure as this is a 3rd party DB.

My current query is:

```
_projectSites = (from de in _data.DataExchange
    join m in _data.Projects_MACO //combine exchange data and maco data
    on new
    {
        Number = de.number,
        IsProject = de.SiteType.Name != "opportunity"
    } equals
    new
    {
        Number = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppNumber : m.ProjectNumber,
        IsProject = m.ProjectNumber != null
    }
    join d in _data.DataStores //and select only sites with datastores
    on new
    {
        Number = de.number
    } equals
    new
    {
        Number = d.SiteNumber
    }
    where de.Server.Name == _server
    select new ProjectSiteNode()
    {
        Server = de.Server.Name,
        ProjectNumber = de.number,
        Manager = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OMInitials : m.PMInitials,
        Exists = true,
        IsConfidential = de.confidential,
        Name = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppTitle : m.ProjectTitle,
        ProjectType = de.SiteType.Name,// m.ProjectNumber == null ? "opportunity" : "project",
        Status = de.SiteState.Name
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

The problematic line is :

```
 IsProject = de.SiteType.Name != "opportunity"
```

**How can I improve the performance of this query?**

Is there some chance how to preload the de.SiteType.Name? I think the problem is probably caused by the fact, that it has to create a query to SiteType table for every `de` row, am I right?

Comment: Check type of IsProject and make sure it is set to Boolean.

Comment: IsProjects is a property of the anonymous objects used for comparison and as you can se - yes, it's boolena

Comment: You did not post the code that shows the definition for IsProject.  All you posted  was the code where you are trying to set a boolean to IsProject and it is failing.  It is not anonymous it is defined in the class ProjectSiteNode().

Comment: Sorry, but no. It is anonymous and is not defined in the class ProjectSIteNode. It's defined only here:
     on new
    {
        Number = de.number,
        IsProject = de.SiteType.Name != "opportunity"
    } equals
    new
    {
        Number = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppNumber : m.ProjectNumber,
        IsProject = m.ProjectNumber != null
    }

Comment: Right click ProjectType and select definition.  It is not anonymous.

Comment: ProjectType is a property of ProjectSiteNode, but we haven't discussed this property yet, we discussed IsProject property. And IsProject is a definitely bool property of anonymous object created just for the join. What is unclear on that? Btw, I didn't mention that the code is failing on the line
 IsProject = de.SiteType.Name != "opportunity"
I wrote that this line causes problesm - meaning, that it causes performance issues.

Comment: You have the following : select new ProjectSiteNode() {}  Everything in the curly brackets must be in the class ProjectSiteNode and can't be anonyomous

Comment: Yes. And where do you see a property called IsProject there?! What is this discussion about??!! ProjectSiteNode object has following properties (as you can see above): Server,        ProjectNumber,Manager,Exists, IsConfidential, Name ,ProjectType and Status but it DOES NOT CONTAIN PROPERTY 'ISPROJECT'!!! Are you blind or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the **solution**!! Wow. The problem is in *!= "opportunity"*. If I used ID instead of string, it takes 0.2s instead of 28s

```
var projectSites = (from d in _data.DataStores
                                     join de in _data.DataExchange
                                     on new
                                     {
                                         Number = d.SiteNumber
                                     } equals
                                     new
                                     {
                                         Number = de.number
                                     }
                                     join m in _data.Projects_MACO //combine exchange data and maco data
                                     on new
                                     {
                                         Number = de.number,
                                         IsProject = de.SiteType.ID != 2
                                     } equals
                                     new
                                     {
                                         Number = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppNumber : m.ProjectNumber,
                                         IsProject = m.ProjectNumber != null
                                     }

                                     where de.Server.Name == _server
                                     select new 
                                     {
                                         Server = de.Server.Name,
                                         ProjectNumber = de.number,
                                         Manager = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OMInitials : m.PMInitials,
                                         Exists = true,
                                         IsConfidential = de.confidential,
                                         Name = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppTitle : m.ProjectTitle,
                                         ProjectType = de.SiteType.Name,// m.ProjectNumber == null ? "opportunity" : "project",
                                         Status = de.SiteState.Name
                                     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has something to with adding logic inside the join-statement for EF4. What happens if you try:

```
_projectSites = (from de in _data.DataExchange
    join m in _data.Projects_MACO //combine exchange data and maco data
    on new
    {
        Number = de.number
    } equals
    new
    {
        Number = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppNumber : m.ProjectNumber
    }
    join d in _data.DataStores //and select only sites with datastores
    on new
    {
        Number = de.number
    } equals
    new
    {
        Number = d.SiteNumber
    }
    where de.Server.Name == _server 
    && de.SiteType.Name != "opportunity" 
    && m.ProjectNumber != null
    select new ProjectSiteNode()
    {
        Server = de.Server.Name,
        ProjectNumber = de.number,
        Manager = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OMInitials : m.PMInitials,
        Exists = true,
        IsConfidential = de.confidential,
        Name = m.ProjectNumber == null ? m.OppTitle : m.ProjectTitle,
        ProjectType = de.SiteType.Name,// m.ProjectNumber == null ? "opportunity" : "project",
        Status = de.SiteState.Name
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: this wouldn't work, because it would filter out only entities which are not "opportunity", however I need only pair the proper records - so project to project, opportunity to opportunity